# loop object, output different html depending on position

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to loop a JSON object with X items and then display the items - However, it has to output different html depending on which position in the loop it is. Ex: Article1 has a different layout than Article2-3-4 - Article5-6-7 has a different layout that the rest, how would I do this with angular, is it possible with directives or do I need something else? If so, how would I do it? I've got this so far:

```
DIS.dbuApp.controller('newsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) { 

    //URL for retrieving JSON object
    $scope.url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.fetchContent = function() {

        $http.get($scope.url)
        .success(function(data, status){
            if(typeof(data === "object") && data.length > 0) {

                console.log("test");

                //We got the data, and it is and object
                $scope.items = data;

                //Now set variable to tru
                $scope.showresult = true;

                //If first item use this directive:

                _.each($scope.items, function(value, index){
                    //console.log(index);
                    if(index === 0) {
                        //When position 0, render a directive with some specific html
                        console.log(index);
                    } else if(index > 0  && index < 5) {
                        //When position greater than 0 and lower than 5, render another directive with some specific html
                        console.log(index);
                    } else if(index > 4 && index < 9) {
                        //Same as above, but with different html
                        console.log(index);
                    } else if(index > 8 && index < 12) {
                        //Same as above, but with different html
                        console.log(index);
                    }
                    _.each(value, function(value, key){
                        //console.log(value + key); // 0: foo, 1: bar, 2: baz
                    });
                });


                //If second to fifth item, use this directive


                //If six to 10, use this directive

            }   

        })
        .error(function() {
            console.log("There was an error, contact the developer, or check your internet connection" + status);
        });
    };

    $scope.fetchContent();

}]);
```

Comment: is it an array or a plain object?

Comment: it's a JSON object, coming from a webservice

Comment: then how do you get the length `data.length`?

Comment: if just a check to see if the object has any values

Comment: object has **no length property** `console.log({}.length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a directive for each data type if you have a finite number of them, say 3-5, and you need very different functionality between them - not just a different layout. In that case you could use ng-switch:

```
<div ng-switch="$index">
   <div ng-switch-when="1" number1directive />
```

Alternatively you can have a single directive, and in the link function, determine the template to render, passing the index into it as isolated scope.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div mydirective item-index="$index" item-data="item" />
</div>
```

The last option will be a lot cleaner and more scalable if they are very similar functionally, with different templates.

**UPDATE:**

An example of a directive using `nginclude` internally.

```
app.directive("dynamicTemplate", function () {
  return {
    template: '<ng-include src="getTemplateUrl()" />',
    scope: {
      index: '@',
      item: '='
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      // function used on the ng-include to resolve the template
      $scope.getTemplateUrl = function () {
        if ($scope.index === 0) {
          return "template0.html";
        } else if ($scope.index > 0 && $scope.index < 5) {
          return "template1-4.html";
        } else if ($scope.index > 4 && $scope.index < 9) {
          return "template5-8.html";
        } else if ($scope.index > 8 && $scope.index < 12) {
          return "template9-11.html";
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Implemented in `HTML` as:

```
<dynamic-template index="$index" item="item"><dynamic-template>
```

This is the idea anyway. Hopefully you'll be able to work with this approach perhaps with some minor refinements.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I quite understand, do you have a working example, or fiddle perhaps? :)

Comment: Do you know how to write a directive?

Comment: Yes, but only simple ones, so a bit confused on how you would only have a single directive, when I need 4 different layout renderings, depending on the position/index in my loop - See the updated code above

Comment: See an updated answer. I'm on my phone so format is a little out but hopefully you get the idea. I'll try tidy it up later.

Comment: Makes sense, but it still doesnt seem to work - If i console.log($scope.index) it returns $index and not the actual index, just the text $index - So it never gets the template ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, rather than index: '@' in the directive , use either & (should work) or = will def. work. (Rather than the @)